# Linear independence in linear applications

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I need to prove that if a set of vectors $S$ is linearly independent, then $f(S)$ is also independent. Assuming f is the next homomorphism of vector spaces:

$$ f : V \rightarrow W$$

**Demonstration attempt**

We assume S is the next set of vectors:

$$ S = \left \{ u_{1}, u_{2},...,u_{n} \right \}$$

By definition of a linearly independent set, we know that the only solution to the equation is the trivial one:

$$\alpha_{1} u_{1} + \alpha_{2} u_{2} + ... + \alpha_{n} u_{n} = 0$$

Then,

$$f(\alpha_{1} u_{1}) + f(\alpha_{2} u_{2}) + ... + f(\alpha_{n} u_{n}) = 0 \Rightarrow  \\
\alpha_{1} f(u_{1}) + \alpha f(u_{2}) + ... + \alpha f(u_{n}) = 0  \Rightarrow \\
\alpha_{1} = ... = \alpha_{n} = 0$$

It is a linearly independent set.
$\blacksquare$

Comment: I did not downvoted you. Whomever did, must give a reason why they did this.

Comment: By the way, @Carlos. what you _are_ proving is that if $f$ and $S$ are such that $f(S)$ is linearly independent, then $S$ is linearly independant.

Comment: However, if the image is linearly independent, the anti-image is also independent?

Comment: Exactly what I wrote one comment above.

Comment: And the demonstration would be similar to mine?

Answer (score 1):

The result is false unless you have extra hypothesis on $f.$ The linear function $f(x) = 0$ already shows this.

Comment: I know that by defining linear transformation that linear dependence if preserved, its demonstration would be similar to what I have tried to pose. So, based on that I have tried to do that proof.

Comment: Can you rephrase that? What are you _trying to prove_?

Comment: I'm trying to show that if a set is linearly independent, so is its image. When I studied linear transformations in Algebra, I observed that if a vector is linearly dependent, the image of the vector is also linearly dependent. Well, based on that proof, I've tried this one.

Comment: I already showed to you that the stament "if a set is linearly independent, so is its image [under a linear transformation]" is _false._ So, no, you cannot.

Comment: So, unless the linear application is $f(x)=0$, the image of an independent linear set doesn't have to be, does it?

Comment: No, you would need $f$ to be an isomorphism (maybe a less restrictive hypothesis would work). For instance, the two vectors $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$ in $\Bbb R^2$ are linearly independent and their image under the linear trasformation $(x, y) \mapsto x$ are $0$ and $1,$ which are linearly dependent (in $\Bbb R$).